# Tooltip works on Second hover not in First

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, tooltip

I have kept a Link button(*Asp.net,c#*) within the nested Data list.

```
Data list1

    --> Data list2

        --> Link Button
```

After page loaded the Tool tip script works on second hover,not in first hover.

**Here is my Script:**

```
$("[id*=LinkButton2]").live("mouseover", function () {
        $("[id*=LinkButton2]").aToolTip({
                fixed: true,
                tipContent: document.getElementById("<%=tax_dl.ClientID%>").innerHTML
            });
        });
```

The Tool tip bounds and displays some value.

*Please let me know if you need more information*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use html 'title' attribute if you want tooltips... Or is there something more complex you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `aToolTip()` is being instantiated on the element on the first hover, and then it runs on subsequent hovers.

You instead you need to attach `aToolTip()` at the point you create the `LinkButton2` element, and not bother with `live()`.